# Windows 7 install fails on Lenovo IdeaPad 330-15IGM. with BSOD or freeze

Tags: windows-7, installation, bsod

A [new Lenovo laptop](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/330-14igm_330-15igm_330-15icn_330-15arr_330touch-15arr_ug_en_201805.pdf)  bought this August came with Windows 10. Windows 8.1 worked on it, except when drivers were missing; [only Windows 10 is supported](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/300-series/330-15igm/downloads). When I try to boot the Windows 7 installation in Legacy mode the "Loading Windows Files" loading screen appears along with the "Starting Windows" boot screen. Shortly after, this Blue Screen error appears every time I try to do so.

[Photo of Blue Screen Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozqPZ.jpg)

If I try it in UEFI mode, it freezes on the "Starting Windows" boot screen and has a weird red bar at the top of the screen. I have secure boot disabled and have tried both UEFI and Legacy mode.

I even tried disabling TPM, and the Optimized OS defaults option. Lastly I flashed the BIOS but still got the same results.

What's the next step to get Windows 7 on my IdeaPad 330-15IGM ([manual](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/330-14igm_330-15igm_330-15icn_330-15arr_330touch-15arr_hmm_201805.pdf))?

Comment: Are you installing Windows 7 with a USB 2 or USB 3 flash drive?

Comment: + Ramhound Actually I was wrong I guess it is 2.0 lol, my bad. I looked up the serial number to double check.  https://www.amazon.com/SanDisk-Flash-Cruzer-Glide-SDCZ60-016G-B35/dp/B007YX9O9O

Comment: +K7AAY You could be right, I just find it odd that 8.1 will install and work out of the box.

Comment: _VampireFox2_, I wish I had something for you, but I don't. Is there a Killer App which only works with Windows 7, or is this a matter of preference? Why do you want Windows 7?

Comment: It's all good, Because it was the OS I grew up with and I greatly dislike 10. Since it will still be supported unitil 2020 I'd figure I'd give it a shot. Anyways thanks, I guess I'll install 8.1 on it instead and theme it up to look like 7. :)

Comment: You may like Classic Shell http://www.classicshell.net/

Comment: Yeah I actually have quite a bit of Stardocks software including Start 8/10 so I'll be able to make it look very close to 7. Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since only Windows 10 is supported, and there are no Windows 7 drivers, it is likely that Windows 7 does not know how to deal with new hardware in your IdeaPad. It is significantly different under the hood than Windows 8.1 and Windows 10.